# exception thrown from TextChanged event for chinese input

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am observing a crash while entering Text in Chinese language to `TextBox` with `TextChanged` event implemented.
The text I am entering is "y "('y' preceding with space).
When I tried to debug the issue in VS 2013, it is showing below exception  in `TextChanged` Event.

> ExcecutionEngineException unhandled

Can somebody help me out on this.
below is sample code for the mentioned event.

```
private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     this.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag.ToString());
     var txtB = (TextBox)sender;
     if (10 < txtB.Text.Length)
     {
         txtB.Text = "";
     }
}
```

Comment: put here the chiense word i want to try it. english and everything else works perfect.

Comment: Yes Slashy, it's working fine with other languages but with few chinese words I am facing the issue. Just  try to press space-bar after 'y' when your system language is set to Chinese.